# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyFile Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, putty

I have a java file(MyFile.java) which is created in Eclipse on my local machine, the compiled class file is placed in client's linux machine under WEB-INF/classes folder i m trying to execute the .class file from linux, i m getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
i have set PATH,JAVA_HOME & CLASSPATH. The classpath is set as : 
export CLASSPATH=WEB-INF/classes/:WEB-INF/lib

I have added lib folder to classpath because i m using a .so file which is used by my java class.

Could anyone please help me how to sort out this?

Comment: does your class have package?

Comment: yes, it has com.abc.sys

Comment: do u want to run your class file , in cmd prompt or in Browser(via servlets)?

Comment: in command prompt(linux), my class has main method, which i want to run on linux machine using putty.

Comment: The problem is in setting classpath, copy your .class file in current working dir of linux terminal , and then run

Comment: currently i m working under root/xyz/forms directory i created a "bin" folder under this & copied all the class files with same structure com.abc.sys folders and tried still getting the same error.                                                          [root in /xyz/forms/bin/com/abc]# java -cp xyz/forms/bin sys.MyFie

Comment: cd bin, then java com.abc.sys.YourClassFileName

Comment: if u r in terminal of linux , type dir, and tell what is the output u r getting.

Comment: all the class files under that folder are listed out

Comment: come out of directory, by typing(in terminal) cd .. (two dots), untill u see com directory

Comment: [root in xyz/forms/bin] java com.abc.sys.MyFile, this is what i tried.Please correct me if i m wrong

Comment: now type dir in terminal, if u see com directory, then java com.abc.sys.MyFile

Comment: [root in /xyz/forms/bin]# dir
com  net
[root in /xyz/forms/bin]# java com.abc.sys.MyFile
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/sys/MyFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.sys.MyFile
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)

Comment: Is your FileName and java Class Name same?

Comment: Can you post the class?

Comment: with -cp, iam not getting error for MyFile.class, but I have different issue now. MyFile is using a.so file,which I have added under lib folder and while executing i include the lib folder as well in the classpath.

Comment: java -cp./classes:./lib com.abc.sys.MyFile , currently im in WEB-INF folder , from where i m trying to run my class file. The .so file is under lib folder of WEB-INF. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mssint/jclib/Var
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mssint.jclib.Var
it is not able to find the dependency files from .so file.

Comment: I even tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH as export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/WEB-INF/lib. but looks like it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
java -cp WEB-INF/classes/:WEB-INF/lib com.abc.sys.MyFile
```

Comment: [root in /]# java -cp WEB-INF/classes:WEB-INF/lib com.abc.sys.MyFile
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mssint/jclib/Var
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mssint.jclib.Var
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at 
Could not find the main class: com.abc.sys.MyFile. Program will exit.

Comment: Are these WEB-INF directory present under current directory form where you are executing you java program? Else try to add the absolute path of the WEB-INF directory in the classpath

Comment: WEB-INF is under root/xyz/forms i tried giving the complete path as well. I m just trying to run .class file from classes folder in WEB-INF

Comment: Couple of things: You must try to execute the program as a root user in that case. Or simply change the working directory to 'root/xyz/forms' and then execute the java program as before.

Comment: are you asking me to compile the java file & then run .class file? Sorry i dint get.

Comment: You said you have already compiled the file right. I am just asking you to run the file by changing you working directory as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I found the solution to my problem, i did not set CLASSPATH variable instead while running i used -cp and set the class path & lib files used & also set LD_LIBARY_PATH and included along with cp. I did cd till WEB-INF and executed the following command:
java -cp ./lib:./classes:$LD_LIBRARY com/abc/sys/MyFile